# document.getElementsByClassName(class) does not get a live copy of the current HTML (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to apply the following function after changing the content but `let elements` keeps getting the same content when `converElemntsToSpanElemnts()`(on click) was fired the first time (old value) if there a way to get a live copy of the current HTML

the function now keeps replacing the new content with the old content that it got at the first time I ran the function

```
converElemntsToSpanElemnts(className) {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);    
    Array.from(elements as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>).forEach((element, index) => {
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/(<div)/igm, '<span').replace(/<\/div>/igm, '</span>');
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/(<app-ckeditor-view-content)/igm, '<span').replace(/<\/app-ckeditor-view-content>/igm, '</span>');
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/(<p)/igm, '<span').replace(/<\/p>/igm, '</span>');
    })
}
```

Comment: The information you provided is a bit too sparse (How and when do you call `converElemntsToSpanElemnts`? Where does the content you're trying to manipulate come from? If it comes from an angular template, why not just change it right there?).

Comment: @lentschi ```converElemntsToSpanElemnts``` get fired on click and the content is regular HTML from another component and it's a bit too big to be displayed

Comment: You should then find a way to communicate with that other component and tell it to change its contents on its own (using `*ngIf="something"; else` in its template code). Usually you do that by adding an input to the other component and modifying its contents on `(click)` (see https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs).

Comment: Don't interact with the Dom directly in angular, use services to handle your data and components to render the html.